# Postgres: Crosstab function alternatives

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like this:

```
ID | Value
------------
1  | ABC
1  | DEF
1  | GHI
2  | JKL
2  | MNO
```

I am looking for an output like this:

```
ID | Column1 | Column2 | Column3
----------------------------------
1  |   ABC   |   DEF   |   GHI     
2  |   JKL   |   MNO   |   NULL
```

Is there a way to achieve this in Postgres without using the crosstab function?

Comment: Another alternative (which is more dynamic) is to aggregate the values into JSON key/value pairs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the values are limited, then you can do conditional aggregation :

```
select id, 
       max(value) filter (where seq = 1) as col1,
       max(value) filter (where seq = 2) as col2,
       max(value) filter (where seq = 3) as co3
from(select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by value) as seq
     from table t
    ) t
group by id;
```

Comment: @Garfield . . . This is the best way to do conditional aggregation in Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `case` statement. here is the [**demo**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6Qn3uxy4QtoSc9q9KfUJ1T/0).

```
select
    id,
    max(case when value in ('ABC', 'JKL') then value end) as column1,
    max(case when value in ('DEF', 'MNO') then value end) as column2,
    max(case when value in ('GHI') then value end) as column3
from myTable
group by
    id
order by
    id
```

Output:

```
id | column1 | column2 | column3
----------------------------------
1  |   ABC   |   DEF   |   GHI     
2  |   JKL   |   MNO   |   null
```